# How to render a partial on specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was planning on displaying a view on specific controller so I tried initating this code below on my views/layouts.rb:

```
if controller == 'home' && action == 'index'
   <%= render 'layouts/sliding_door' %>
end
```

of course this did not work. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `controller_name` and `action_name` available in views:

```
<% if controller_name == 'home' && action_name == 'index' %>
  <%= render 'layouts/sliding_door' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use an instance variable to determine whether or not the `layouts/sliding_door` partial should be added or not.

In the controller you could add:

```
@sliding_door = true
```

And the view would then have:

```
<%= render 'layouts/sliding_door' if @sliding_door %>
```

This would make it easier to toggle this to other actions and controllers as well in future, instead of adding a check for new controller and action names each time this needs to be rendered.